# Is there an exploit for python hash collision?

Tags: denial-of-service, python

Is there an exploit for [this](http://bugs.python.org/issue13703) vulnerability?

EDIT

Python DoS via hash algorithm collision - [oCERT advisory 2011-003](http://www.ocert.org/advisories/ocert-2011-003.html). Affected numerous languages. No CVE for Python but CVEs for other languages.

Comment: It would be VERY helpful to post the CVE or other details in the question. That way we don't have to hunt through several layers of information to figure out what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

Please look at how SipHash replaced old hash mechanism to counter-measure DoS through hash collision.

https://131002.net/siphash/#at

-> Slides of the presentation "Hash-flooding DoS reloaded: attacks and defenses"